# Treeview内リストを固定幅にし、横スクロールバーを有効にしたい。

Tags: python, python3

解決策をご存知の方にご教示をお願いいたします。

**実現したいこと**
大きさの決まったダイアログおよびLabelFrame内で、Treeviewを使用して表を表示したいです。
表は見やすいように、カラムを項目に合わせて固定幅とします。そのため、決められた大きさの中で、Treeview上の表は表示しきれないので、縦横のスクロールバーが埋め込む有効な状態としたいです。

**現在の問題点**
・Treeview上の表全体の幅が収めたい幅にならない。
・Treeviewの幅が抑えられないので、横スクロールバーが有効にならない。

**サンプルコード**
LabelFrame内にTreeviewおよびscrollbarを配置します。
Treeviewには全体の幅するオプションがないので、LabelFrame.columnconfigureで指定するが無視されて、Treeviewの表データに合わせた幅になってしまっています。

**試したこと**
以下のリンクについて、試しました。
私の用途では、place()による配置は適していないため、2つ目のリンクの内容は参考になりませんでした。
[Horizontal scrolling won't activate for ttk Treeview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359906/horizontal-scrolling-wont-activate-for-ttk-treeview-widget)
[python ttk Notebookにtreeviewをグリッドで配置した時にスクロールバーが収まらない](https://teratail.com/questions/139274)

---

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_w = 300
        self.screen_h = 200
        self.dlg_pos_x = 10
        self.dlg_pos_y = 10

        return super().__init__()

    def createMainWindow(self):

        obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        _InFrame_ = ttk.LabelFrame(
            obj,
            width = self.screen_w,
            height = self.screen_h,
            text = "決められた幅のフレーム内で表示したい。",
            )

        _TreeList_ = ttk.Treeview(
            _InFrame_,
            selectmode = 'none',
            show = "headings",
            height = 6,
            )

        tree_h_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            _InFrame_,
            orient = tk.HORIZONTAL,
            command = _TreeList_.xview
            )

        tree_v_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            _InFrame_,
            orient = tk.VERTICAL,
            command = _TreeList_.yview
            )

        _TreeList_['xscrollcommand'] = tree_h_scroll.set
        _TreeList_['yscrollcommand'] = tree_v_scroll.set

        tree = _TreeList_
        tree["columns"]=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
        tree.heading("#0",text = "")
        tree.heading(1,text = "項")
        tree.heading(2,text = "名前")
        tree.heading(3,text = "型式")
        tree.heading(4,text = "単価")
        tree.heading(5,text = "在庫数")
        tree.heading(6,text = "備考")

        tree.column(1, width = 30, stretch = False)
        tree.column(2, width = 100, stretch = False)
        tree.column(3, width = 150, stretch = False)
        tree.column(4, width = 50, stretch = False)
        tree.column(5, width = 50, stretch = False)
        tree.column(6, width = 150, stretch = False)

        tree_value = list()

        #適当にデータを埋め込む。
        for i in range(32):
            tree_value.append((i,"tree"+str(i),"T-"+str(i),i%5*1000+100,i%2*50,"*******"))

        for ch, val in enumerate(tree_value):
            tree.insert("",index = "end",tags = ch%2,value=val)
        else:
            tree.tag_configure(0,background = "lightcyan")
            tree.tag_configure(1,background = "white")

        _InFrame_.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
        _InFrame_.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 250)
        _TreeList_.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W  )
        tree_h_scroll.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = tk.EW )
        tree_v_scroll.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = tk.NS )

        return obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _InFrame_.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
 _InFrame_.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 250)
 _TreeList_.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W  )
 tree_h_scroll.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = tk.EW )
 tree_v_scroll.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = tk.NS )
```

の箇所を

```
 _InFrame_.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
 # 1列目を可変サイズとする
 _InFrame_.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
 # 1行目を可変サイズとする        
 _InFrame_.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
 # 内部のサイズに合わせたフレームサイズとしない
 _InFrame_.grid_propagate(False)
 _TreeList_.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W  )
 tree_h_scroll.grid(row = 1,column = 0,sticky = tk.EW )
 tree_v_scroll.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = tk.NS )
```

とすると良いかと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとございます。
grid_propagateというメソッドをしりませんでした。目的の動作になりました。

Answer (score 1):

回答では無くて、上記質問の先に作ろうとしているらしきもの、の情報です。
おそらく`DataGridView`のような感じでデータの表示と操作もやろうとしていると思われますが、こんなライブラリがあります。
データ連携機能も組み込まれていて、開発量が減らせるのではないでしょうか。
[dmnfarrell/tkintertable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable)

さらには同じ作者が pandas と連携した同様(おそらくもっと高機能)のライブラリを作っています。
[dmnfarrell/pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable)

英語版StackOverflowの記事に、こんなのがあって、2番目の記事の回答がPython2.x用なんですが、これをPython3.x用に直す(2to3.pyに通す)と、@magichanさん回答のようなウインドウが表示されます。
[Does tkinter have a table widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9348264/9014308)
[Tkintertable Get selected Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19402998/9014308)

途中にある`self.table.model.load('save.table')`の`save.table`は、`tkintertable`リポジトリの`sample.table`に直して使っています。

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
from tkintertable.TableModels import TableModel

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.model = TableModel()
        self.table = TableCanvas(self, model=self.model)
        self.table.createTableFrame()
        root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.clicked)   #Bind the click release event

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.table.model.load('sample.table')  #You don't have to load a model, but I usually
        self.table.redrawTable()             #Create a base model for my tables.

        d = dir(self.table)  #Will show you what you can do with tables.  add .model
                             #to the end to see what you can do with the models.
        for i in d:
            print(i)

    def clicked(self, event):  #Click event callback function.
        #Probably needs better exception handling, but w/e.
        try:
            rclicked = self.table.get_row_clicked(event)
            cclicked = self.table.get_col_clicked(event)
            clicks = (rclicked, cclicked)
            print('clicks:', clicks)
        except: 
            print('Error')
        if clicks:
            #Now we try to get the value of the row+col that was clicked.
            try: print('single cell:', self.table.model.getValueAt(clicks[0], clicks[1]))
            except: print('No record at:', clicks)

            #This is how you can get the entire contents of a row.
            try: print('entire record:', self.table.model.getRecordAtRow(clicks[0]))
            except: print('No record at:', clicks)

root = Tk()
root.title('Table Test')
app = Application(master=root)
print('Starting mainloop()')
app.mainloop()
```

[image: tkintertableの使い方サンプル表示]

Comment: ありがとございます。詳しく見てみます。標準的なライブラリを使用することを前提に作っているため、GitHubから目的のものを探してみることをあまりしてきませんでした。
今は、Windowsアプリケーションを制作中ですが、Linuxにそのままソースを持っていこうと考えています。こうした場合、いろいろなライブラリを使用して、移植性は大丈夫なのでしょうか？

Comment: 個別のハードウェアに依存する機能を細かく制御するものでない限り問題はありません。これもTkinterがベースになっているので、元から移植性は確保されています。