# 読み込んだファイルを Tkinter で表にして出力したい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

あらかじめ用意されたテキストファイルをtkinterを利用して表形式で出力したいと考えています。空白を確認したら次の列、改行を確認したら次の行に出力されることを想定しています。しかしどのようにプログラムを組めばそのような結果になるか分かりません。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/トポロジー情報の出力.py", line 29, in <module>
    tree.insert(parent='', index=0, iid=0, values=(i,line))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1341, in insert
    "-id", iid, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item 0 already exists
```

**現状のコード:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import LEFT
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# ファイルの呼び出し
path = fd.askopenfilename()

# メインウィンドウの生成
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("表形式で出力")

frame = Frame(root)

# Treeviewの生成
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1,2), show='headings', height=20)

# 列の見出し設定
tree.heading(1, text="1")
tree.heading(2, text="2")

i = 0
# テキストファイルの読み込み
with open(path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        i = i + 1
        tree.insert(parent='', index=0, iid=0, values=(i,line))
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# ウィジェットの配置
frame.pack()
tree.pack(side=LEFT)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: 現状のコードではどのような問題があるのかを説明した方が、回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: この記事 [Treeview内リストを固定幅にし、横スクロールバーを有効にしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/56104/26370) や私の回答で紹介している[tkintertable 1.3.3 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tkintertable/) が参考になるのでは？ 実際に使うデータファイルの例を抜粋したり、それをtkinter上でどのように表示したいかイメージで追加提示すると的確な助言・回答が出やすいと思われます。

Comment: 少しコードを修正してみたところ別のエラーが発生しました。コードを確認してください。エラーは「NameError: name 'scrollbar' is not defined」です。

Comment: "button"についても未定義のようですのでご確認ください。

Answer (score 1):

テーブルの作り方は[テーブル（表）の作成方法（Treeview）](https://office54.net/python/tkinter/ttk-treeview-table)が参考になるかと思います。

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import LEFT
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# ファイルの呼び出し
path = fd.askopenfilename()

# メインウィンドウの生成
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("表形式で出力")

frame = Frame(root)

# Treeviewの生成
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1,2), show='headings', height=20)

# 列の見出し設定
tree.heading(1, text="1")
tree.heading(2, text="2")

i = 0
# テキストファイルの読み込み
with open(path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tree.insert(parent='', index=i, iid=i, values=(line.split())) ### 修正
        i = i + 1
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# ウィジェットの配置
frame.pack()
tree.pack(side=LEFT)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview) ### 追加
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
# button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

※ `scrollbar`は`NameError`が出ましたのでこちらでコードを追加しました。
※ `button`は`NameError`が出ましたのでコメントアウトしました。